# Prevent Serilog from writing HTTP events by default

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I'm [injecting typed HTTP clients](https://www.parksq.co.uk/dotnet-core/dependency-injection-httpclient-and-ihttpclientfactory) in a .NET Core app. I'm also logging with Serilog. I have not intentionally configured any logging of HTTP activity. It magically came with. How do I turn this off?

```
[12:00:52 INF] Start processing HTTP request POST https://foo/bar
[12:00:52 INF] Sending HTTP request POST https://foo/bar
[12:00:53 INF] Received HTTP response after 707.8906ms - OK
```

My HTTP client configuration:

```
services.AddHttpClient("FOO")
    .ConfigureHttpClient(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://foo/");
        })
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(sp => new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass"),
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (senderC, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true
        })
    .AddTypedClient<Thing1>()
    .AddTypedClient<Thing2>();
```

Comment: Do you have a SerilogTraceListener active sucking all output made using System.Diagnostics.Trace into serilog?

Comment: @BenVoigt I did not explicitly set that up, so... maybe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into this and was able to address using Serilog's `Filter` configuration. Not sure where documented ([this appears to be related](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-filters-expressions)), but one avenue is to implement the `ILogEventFilter` interface ([source](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/9a46e68d3e224b965f4ac2665fd379ae9568d6b4/src/Serilog/Core/ILogEventFilter.cs)). Include logic for allowing an event, and plug into configuration.

Example filter class:

```
public class MyLoggingFilter : ILogEventFilter
{
    private static readonly HashSet<string> ignoredMessages = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.Ordinal)
    {
        "Start processing HTTP request {HttpMethod} {Uri}",
        "End processing HTTP request after {ElapsedMilliseconds}ms - {StatusCode}"
    };

    // Allow the event to be logged if the message template isn't one we ignore
    public bool IsEnabled(LogEvent logEvent) => !ignoredMessages.Contains(logEvent.MessageTemplate.Text);
}
```

Added to configuration (Program.cs in this case):

```
config
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Filter.With<MyLoggingFilter>() // <-- Plug in your filter type
    .WriteTo.Console(theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Code)
    .WriteTo.Debug()
    // etc
```

Alternatively, if you want to prevent any logging related to HttpClient, override the category (which is the type namespace) with desired log level:

```
config.MinimumLevel.Override("System.Net.Http.HttpClient", LogEventLevel.Warning)
```

Comment: That seems like a band-aid. I'm still hoping for a solution that prevents `HttpClient` from logging all this junk in the first place.

Comment: Fair point, I wanted to receive part of them but not all. I updated the answer with the override method to prevent any logs from HttpClient.

Comment: I also learned that `HttpClient` only spams the log when `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is "Development". Still unexpected and annoying.

Comment: That's good to know, I will have to see about logging in production.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski I used the second part of this answer, setting the minimum level for `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to add an override for `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` to `appsettings.json`:
[image]